# Other users(that are not logged in to Google) can’t run my google app script on my google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I wrote some Google apps script for a roster planer. Some of them should be accessable by everyone some not. Is there any way I can forgive Permissions (even if they are not signed in)? At the moment nobody except me can run them they all get the error: `Error by running script ...`.

**Sample code:**

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet3=ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt3")

function search() {
  var buffer=[];
  reset();
  var data2=[[]];
  var data;
  var name=sheet3.getRange(6,2).getValue();
  for(var x=1;!sheet3.getRange(1,x).isBlank();x++){}
  data=sheet3.getRange(1,1,4,x-1).getValues();
  for(var x=1;x<data.length;x++){
    for(var y=0;y<data[x].length;y++){
      if(data[x][y]==name){
        sheet3.getRange(1,y+1,4,1).setBorder(true, true, true, true,
false, false, 'blue', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        buffer=[];
        buffer.push(data[0][y])
        for(var z=1;z<4;z++){
          buffer.push(data[z][y]);
        }
        data2.push(buffer);
      }
    }
  }
return data2;
}
```

Comment: How is this code being triggered? From a button/menu/on edit/script tool...?

Comment: It's triggered through a button(drawing with script added)